# Get all keys from object that have a specific value

Tags: javascript, object, key

I have an object named `x`. It looks similar to this:

```js
{
  a: 123,
  b: null,
  c: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

I want to get the names of all the keys that are truthy, so I need to get an array that looks something like `["a", "c"]`, because `x.a` and `x.c` are truthy, but `x.b` is not. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var x = {
  a: 123,
  b: null,
  c: [1, 2, 3]
}

var y = Object.keys(x).filter(item => !!x[item])
console.log(y)
```

The `!!` operator, quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784946/12984567):

> Converts `Object` to `boolean`. If it was falsey (e.g. `0`, `null`, `undefined`, etc.), it will be `false`, otherwise, `true`.

So, assuming `truthyValue` is truthy and `falsyValue` is falsy, `!!truthyValue` will always be `true`, and `!!falseyValue` will always be false.